# Freeing a struct from a callback that is a field of the struct

Tags: c

Consider this code:

```
typedef struct Test_s Test;

typedef void (*FreePtr)(Test*);

struct Test_s{
    FreePtr freePtr;
};
    
void freeFunction(Test* t) {
    free(t);
}
void main(void) {
    Test* t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    t->freePtr = freeFunction;
    t->freePtr(t);
}
```

Is it possible to free `t` from within `freeFunction`? I think it is possible, but I decided to ask as I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're concerned that you're freeing the pointer that you indirected through to get to the function that's running. This isn't a problem.

```
t->freePtr(t);
```

is equivalent to

```
Freeptr tempfunc = t->freePtr;
tempfunc(t);
```

As you can see from this rewrite, `t` is not still in use while the function is running.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unusual setup, but, yes, it's safe what you are doing. You are not accessing "free"d memory after it's been freed or anything.

---

Apart from the `t->freePtr(t)` call that may raise an eyebrow (but is fine), a suggestion is to use `main` signatures that are portable **unless** you have a specific reason not to:

```c
int main(void) { // <- very portable signature
```